# Enumerate JSON Array Elements in Postgresql

Tags: json, postgresql, jsonb, postgresql-13

Is there a way to query jsonb array items with their order enumerated in postgresql?

For example:

```
SELECT * FROM jsonb_array_elements('[1,2,[3,4]]'::jsonb)
```

Results:

```
value
1
2
[3, 4]
```

I would like these results:

```
key value
0   1
1   2
2   [3, 4]
```

Since I think I can safely assume that any select statement not explicitly ordered is unordered, I do not think a simple ROW_NUMBER() would work reliably in this instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operator `with ordinality` will generate the array index values:

```
SELECT idx, value
FROM jsonb_array_elements('[1,2,[3,4]]'::jsonb) with ordinality as t(value, idx)
order by idx
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. I think "technically" it would be idx-1 here, for the query in the above question, for proper array mapping..